# DropDownList not dispaying MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> TeamTaskSearchDetails1(string claimId, string type)
 {
            int eqClaimId;
            if (false == int.TryParse(claimId, out eqClaimId))
                return null;

        var AssigineeList = await this.handsService.GetTeamTask();
        var content = from p in AssigineeList.Data.ToList()
                      orderby p.claimid
                      select new { p.claimid, p.Assiginee };
        var serviceResult = await this.handsService.GetTeamTaskDetails(Convert.ToString(eqClaimId));
        var claim = serviceResult.ServiceResponse;
        var authorizationData = this.AuthorizationData();
        var regId = authorizationData.CurrentRegionId;
        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        xdoc = XDocument.Parse(claim);
        var result = xdoc.Element("Claim").Descendants();


        var StartDate = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "StartDate").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var EndDate = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "EndDate").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var ForensicDueDate = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ForensicDueDate").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var FirstName = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FirstName").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var status = xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "status").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        Equip.Models.TeamTaskSearchDetails.ClaimDetails claimdtl = new Equip.Models.TeamTaskSearchDetails.ClaimDetails()
        {

            StartDate = StartDate,
            EndDate = EndDate,
            ForensicDueDate = ForensicDueDate,
            FirstName = FirstName,
            status = status,
        };
        var x = content.ToList().Select(c => new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.Assiginee,
            Value =Convert.ToInt32(c.claimid).ToString(),
        },

        }).ToList();

        ViewBag.Task = x;
        this.ViewBag.Type = type;
        return this.PartialView("_TeamTaskClaimSearch", claimdtl);
    }
```

Model Class:

```
 public class ClaimDetails
{

    public int Assigineeid { get; set; }

    public List<ClaimDetails> AssigineeList { get; set; }
    public int  ID { get; set; }
    public string claimid { get; set; }
    //public List<SelectListItem> claimid { get; set; }
    public string contactID { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ForensicDueDate { get; set; }
    public string ForensicDueTime { get; set; }
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PreScreen { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Edit { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }


    public string Assiginee
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName ?? string.Empty, this.LastName ?? string.Empty).Trim();
        }
        set
        {

        }

    }
     public string Patient
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.PatientFirstName ?? string.Empty, this.PatientLastName ?? string.Empty).Trim();
        }

    }

}

}
```

View to Bind DropDown:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.claimid, new SelectList(ViewBag.Task, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown" }))
```

I need to Bind Assiginee in DropDownList,upto values are coming to controller

[image]

Comment: Try `@Html.DropDownList("Task", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown" })`

Comment: Rather than using `ViewBag`, you may create a `SelectList` property under `ClaimDetails` model and pass it to view like `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.claimid, Model.SelectionList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown" }))`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the fields it need to take for value and text

```
 var x = content.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem

            {
                Text = c.Assiginee,
                Value =Convert.ToInt32(c.claimid).ToString(),
            }

           ).ToList();


 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.claimid, new SelectList(ViewBag.Task,  "Value", "Text" , new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown" }))
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.

Comment: Please help it.

Comment: actually for every object u are adding List< SelectListItem> .  So u hav a List<List<SelectListItem>>.  See the updated answer

Comment: Welcome .Accept the answer  :)